# EF Core: How to get results from a PostgreSQL function with refcursor return type

Tags: .net, postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I have this function in PostgreSQL:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public."test_func"(in ref refcursor, in id int) 
RETURNS refcursor AS $$
BEGIN
  OPEN ref FOR 
    SELECT *
    FROM "test_table"
    WHERE "Id" = id;
  RETURN ref;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

You normally get results from this function in SQL like this:

```sql
select public."test_func"('my_cursor', 1);

fetch all in "my_cursor";
```

I want to get results from this function in EF Core but couldn't figure out how. I tried to execute the select and fetch all in `context.test_table.FromSqlInterpolated()` but it gives `The required column 'Id' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation.` error which I assume because of the first SQL command only returning cursor name. I can't create a view because it has a parameter.

Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: It would be so much easier if the function was define as `returns setof table` instead (and then you could also get rid of PL/pgSQL). Additionally: `= @id` is invalid in PL/pgSQL

Comment: Since you omitted the *argmode* for the parameter ref Postgres assumes it is INPUT. ([From the documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) "The mode of an argument: IN, OUT, INOUT, or VARIADIC. If omitted, the default is IN".  So perhaps `public."test"(inout ref refcursor, in id int) ...`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Thanks. I fixed "@id" and tried again but same result.

Comment: @Belayer: I added "in" to refcursor, same error. I tried setting it to "inout" and removing "return ref", same error.

Comment: Cross-posted as https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/2700, see there for answers.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I overlooked it is a function. Typically you use an INOUT in a [procedure()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-createprocedure.html) and do have a `return`; with a [function()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) you omit the parameter and define it in the `declare` section, and must have a `return` type. However, an `in` parameter cannot be changed in the code, but an open cursor would actually change the value; so it must be `inout` (version 14 and higher it could just be `out`). So

```
create or replace function public.test_func( in id int) 
  returns refcursor 
 language plpgsql
as $$
declare  
   ref refcursor;
begin
  open ref for 
    select *
    from test_table
    where "Id" = id;
  return ref;
end;
$$;
```

OR

```
create or replace procedure public.test_proc(inout ref refcursor, in id int) 
 language plpgsql
as $$
begin
  open ref for 
    select *
    from test_table
    where "Id" = id;
end;
$$;
```